# Best practice to write new line in C#

Tags: c#, newline, console.writeline

I would like to know which is the best way to write new line in a console application which one is cross-platform.

Which one is the best way to do it (if has any):

- `Console.WriteLine();`
- `Console.WriteLine("");`
- `Console.WriteLine("\n");`
- `Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);`

I don't like the `\n` escape sequence when I write an empty line. I prefer the first option but I'm not sure that every program (+ IDE, compiler) will recognize it without the "" marks.

Comment: Mureinik is right and also, if you want to use the hotkey to write it faster  in visual studio, juste write "cw" then press TAB .

Comment: I wonder where your belief comes from that `Console.WriteLine()` wouldn't be supported by a C# compiler...

Comment: Why are people down voting? The persons question is well formatted and shows they also did some ”research” on their own...

Comment: @G.LC Well if he would have done any research he would have probaply noticed that Console.WriteLine already makes a new line.

Comment: @Christophe Gudlake Thanks, best tip!

Comment: @ elgonzo Once time I wrote code in another IDE and it's marked it as error (red line), that's why I added this part.

Comment: @G.LC & @Twenty I exactly know that it makes a new line... I just wanted to make sure that I do everything fine with the `Console.WriteLine()` when I use it. I read something about `\r\t` when I google about the new line and they wrote that the `\r` is not fit for Linux. So again, I just wanted to make sure I won't run any problem with WriteLine().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine()` will take care of the line ending for you. No need for any argument in it.

Comment: Thanks Mureinik! So, can I use it safe and I will not get any compatibility problem when I run the program in an other OP system?